# Calling a method from a different ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm writing a program for managing a tool inventory and have run into a problem when I have the users mark a tool as 'fixed'.

The program should work as follows:

*Using TIView, TIViewModel, TIModel:*

1. Employee checks tool out.
2. Tool happens to get damaged during use.
3. Employee return's the tool marking it as damaged and reporting the problem.
4. The tool is marked as returned and locked from being check out until fixed.

---

*Using VPRView, VPRViewModel, and VPRModel:*

5. An inspector goes into a data grid showing all tools with problems.
6. The inspector corrects the problem, marks the tool as fixed, then submits the data.
7. The program updates the SQLite database with the inspectors ID number, their solution, marks the problem as fixed and logs the date/time of completion.

---

THE PROBLEM STEP:

**8. The program then runs the PopulateToolInventory method from the TIViewModel to update the inventory list so that the tool is no longer locked.**

---

Summarized:

When the inspector marks the tool as fixed the database is updated using the VPRView, VPRViewModel, and VPRModel. The method to pull the data for the tool inventory is found in the TIViewModel. How do I get the application to execute the 'PopulateToolInventory' method from the VPRViewModel after uploading the data to the database via the VPRViewModel?

Code Sample:

**VPRViewModel:**

```
    public void SubmitSolution()
    {
        VPRModel vprm = new VPRModel();
        vprm.SubmitProblemSolution(ProblemSolved, ProblemSolution, InspectorID, SelectedReport[0].ToString());
        ProblemReports = vprm.RetrieveProblemReports();
        InspectorID = null;
        ProblemSolution = null;
        ProblemSolved = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Solution successfully recorded!", "Success!", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        // This is where I would want to call the method from the TIViewModel to update the data grid on the TIView.
    }
```

**TIViewModel:**

```
private DataTable _toolInventory;
public DataTable ToolInventory
    {
        get { return _toolInventory; }
        set
        {
            _toolInventory = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ToolInventory);
        }
    }

public void PopulateToolInventory()
    {
        TIModel tim = new TIModel();
        ToolInventory = tim.RetrieveToolInventory();
    }
```

**ShellViewModel:**

```
class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    public void Open_ToolInventory()
    {
        ActivateItem(new TIViewModel());
    }
    public void ViewProblemReport()
    {
        WindowManager wm = new WindowManager();
        VPRViewModel vprvm = new VPRViewModel();
        wm.ShowDialog(vprvm);
    }
}
```

**FYI: I'm using Caliburn.Micro if this helps with any solution.**

Hopefully this is enough information. If not, just ask for what you need! Also, please don't eat my code alive. I'm self taught and know that I'm far from a professional developer but this is a passion of mine and I'm really enjoying it. Constructive criticism is appreciated, just please don't make me feel stupid.

Comment: See: https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator

Comment: This looks like it could be a solution. I'm having a little trouble understanding how to actually call the method via the EventAggregator once it's established on the TIViewModel though.

Comment: Where is your instance of `TIViewModel`? Are it and the `VPRViewModel` instance both children of the same parent? If so, give `VPRViewModel` a `SolutionSubmitted` event, and have the parent set up a handler that makes `TIViewModel` do whatever it needs to. Or do you have a scheme where the views create their own viewmodels, so they can't talk to each other? The latter is a bad idea; it gets MVVM backwards. Don't touch anything with event aggregators or locators; those are byzantine, needless kludges designed to enable the anti-pattern of view-centric design.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Both of them are created by the ShellViewModel. ShellViewModel creates the TIViewModel and TIView on creation and places them in a content area. VPRViewModel and VPRView are both created later on via a menu item. I will update the question to show you the ShellViewModel code.

Comment: If ShellViewModel creates them both and keeps references to them around, that makes the problem pretty simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ed's idea in the question comments I did the following.

```
class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    public void Open_ToolInventory()
    {
        ActivateItem(new TIViewModel());
    }
    public void ViewProblemReport()
    {
        WindowManager wm = new WindowManager();
        VPRViewModel vprvm = new VPRViewModel();
        wm.ShowDialog(vprvm);
    }
}
```

Was changed to:

```
class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    TIViewModel tivm = new TIViewModel();
    VPRViewModel vprvm = new VPRViewModel();

    public void OpenToolInventory()
    {
        ActivateItem(tivm);
    }
    public void ViewProblemReport()
    {
        WindowManager wm = new WindowManager();
        wm.ShowDialog(vprvm);
        tivm.PopulateToolInventory();
    }
}
```

This runs the targeted method after the dialog is closed updating the tool inventory to reflect all the solved problems at once.  You're the best, Ed!